# How to pass in key value pair to MSet in redis golang?

Tags: go, redis, interface

MSet in redis-go accepts `pairs ...interface{}` [here](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/master/commands.go#L807)

```golang
func (c *cmdable) MSet(pairs ...interface{}) *StatusCmd {
    args := make([]interface{}, 1, 1+len(pairs))
    args[0] = "mset"
    args = appendArgs(args, pairs)
    cmd := NewStatusCmd(args...)
    c.process(cmd)
    return cmd
}
```

Now, I have `keys []string` mapped to `values []int64` to be set in Redis cache. How do I convert them to slice of interfaces and pass them to `MSet` to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a for loop to copy the keys and values to a slice:

```
var pairs []interface{}
for i := range keys {
  pairs = append(pairs, keys[i], values[i])
}
cmd := c.MSet(pairs...)
```